# Test the convergence of the series $1+\frac 1 {2^2}+\frac {2^2}{3^3}+\frac {3^3}{4^4}+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> A series is given by $$1+\frac 1 {2^2}+\frac {2^2}{3^3}+\frac {3^3}{4^4}+\cdots$$

**My Try**: I can write this series as $1+\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n^n}{{(n+1)}^{n+1}}$. Then how should I proceed to to check whether it is convergent or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because
$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^{-1}$$

the series is equivalent to the Harmonic series, hence divergent by the [Limit Comparison test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_Comparison_Test):

If $a_n$ denotes the $n$th term,
$$a_n=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\cdot\frac1{n+1}\sim\frac{e^{-1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: You can use `\xrightarrow[aaaaaa]{bbbbb}` to get $\xrightarrow[aaaaaa]{bbbbb}$ for better optics

Comment: $a_n=\frac {n^n}{{(n+1)}^{n+1}}$@barto

Comment: @SubratKumarJena See edit. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$@barto

Comment: @SubratKumarJena So how does $a_n$ relate to $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$? And how does that give us divergence?

Comment: @SubratKumarJena $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ does nog imply convergence of the sum. Try the sequence consisting of one $1$, two $\frac{1}{2}$, three $\frac{1}{3}$, ... , $n$ times $\frac{1}{n}$, etc. Then $a_n \to 0$, but the sum diverges.

Comment: that's i know.but how can i show that it is divergent@hetebrij

Comment: @SubratKumarJena I used the Comparison test; see the link in my answer. I'm sure you've heard of it, perhaps under another name.

Answer (score 4):

Use $(1+\frac1n)^n\to e$ to show that your series is asymptotically equivalent to the harmonic series.

Comment: Not "equivalent to the Harmonic series" (words and terminology matter): "equivalent to $e$ times the Harmonic series."

Comment: @ClementC.: I believe LutzL wording is correct. $a_n$ is *asymptotically equivalent* to $b_n$ if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=C\neq 0$, so there is nothing wrong in stating that the given series is asymptotically equivalent to the harmonic series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The standard equivalence (in the Landau sense) of functions or series is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Generalizations_and_related_usages) with $C=1$, at least in all textbooks or references I have seen.

Comment: Well, if $C$ is a non-zero constant it does not make any difference, so why to nitpick over an irrelevant detail?

Comment: It was a nitpick, now blown out of proportion. But from my experience as a TA, there is so much confusion about equivalence, asymptotics, big-Oh, etc. that using the specific term in the precise way (say, on a site dedicated to math users and learners, read by many students currently learning the concepts) is a good idea.

Comment: @ClementC.: I'd say it depends whom you are teaching. Mathematics students should be able to see the general form and where it fails as equivalence as another example where one has to avoid division by zero. For engineering students go ahead and teach the reduction of the limit to 1 to get a safe result.